# Form with two submits.. How to programmatically submit through javascript a particular submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form with two different submit buttons.  I take a different action in php when each different submit is clicked.  That is working perfectly fine.

My problem is that when one of the submits is clicked I want to pop up a "Are you sure you want to do this?" box.  Then when they click 'yes' I want to submit the form with the button they clicked.

I also don't want to set that submit to be default and then risk having them push enter and take the "are you sure" action without clicking yes.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a little jQuery to add a submit handler to forms with class `needsConfirmation` so that it doesn't submit if the user doesn't confirm the action.  It uses the native javascript `confirm` method.  Altering it to use a jQuery UI dialog is doable but requires a bit more set up.

```
$('form.needsConfirmation').submit( function() {
   return confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
});

<!-- does not need confirming -->
<form action="/example.com/safe"> 
...
</form>

<!-- does need confirming -->
<form action="/example.com/dangerous" class="needsConfirmation">
...
</form>
```